# How to grep a particular keyword from a long phrase of text using Unix command?

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I am bit stuck with this, not getting how to find the keyword in an entire file and matching, the entire word should be printed.

Suppose if I want to search the keyword: `file_demo`

The only matching word in the data below is *file_demo_2021.txt*

The output should be: `file_demo_2021.txt`

**Below is my data in file:**

*For several generations, stories from Africa have traditionally been passed down by word of mouth. Often, after a hard day’s work, the adults would gather the children together by moonlight, around a village fire and tell stories. This was traditionally called 'Tales by Moonlight'. Usually, the stories are meant to prepare young people for life, and so each story taught a lesson or moral. file_demo_2021.txt In the African folktales, the stories reflect the culture where diverse types of animals abound. The animals and birds are often accorded human attributes, so it is not uncommon to find animals talking, singing, or demonstrating other human characteristics such as greed, jealousy, honesty, etc. The setting in many of the stories exposes the reader to the land form and climate within that region of Africa. References are often made to different seasons such as the 'dry' or 'rainy' season and their various effects on the surrounding vegetation and animal life.*

In this data this is one file name, I need to print it as below:

**Output :**

```
file_demo_2021.txt
```

Comment: You show that you want to print a line that has the target string `file_demo` at the start, i.e. `file_demo_2021.txt` but do you also want to print strings that have the target string in the middle or at the end, e.g. `myfile_demonstration` or should it ONLY be at the start? You include `.` in the string you print - what if the text was `file_demo.`, should the `.` be printed then too?

Comment: In most contexts `file_demo_2021.txt` wouldn't be considered a "word" since it contains `.` which is not a word-consituent character by standard definitions (alpha-numeric and `_` are the word-constituent characters). So - what is considered a "word" in your context?

Answer (score 1):

Just use grep

```
grep -oP "file_demo.*\.txt" filename
```

to find any file_demo*.txt

```
grep -oP "file_demo.*[\s]" filename
```

to find any file_demo.* until word separator (space, commas, end of string, etc)

Comment: There's nothing in either of those 2 grep commands that would require `-P` (or even `-E`). Also, the opposite of `\s` is `\S`, you don't need to write `[^\s]`. They do require GNU grep for `-o` and `\S` (or `\s`) though so it'd be worth saying that.

Comment: They don't do what you say though `find any file_demo.* until word separator (space, commas, end of string, etc)`. The first would find `file_demo this is bad .txt` (i.e. include blanks or punctuation etc before .txt) while the second would find `file_demo,` (i.e. including the punctuation `,` at the end).

Comment: As I can see topicstarter is looking for "for suppose if i want to search keyword : file_demo
The only matching word in below data is file_demo_2021.txt", so he is looking for "word" and word separator should be exactly what he want. The only issue is file extention, but it could be fixed if we know that file extention is mandatory or now. So he can try both way and check if they fit his requirements

Comment: There is no word separator in your commands. `\s` means "space", it doesn't mean "word-separator" or "non-word-character" - punctuation can also separate words. Having said that, the OP has included a punctuation character (`.`) in the example "word" `file_demo_2021.txt` so it becomes difficult to know what they mean by a "word". I am about 99.9% sure, though, that given input like `I have file_demo, etc. as .txt files` the desired output would not be `file_demo, etc. as .txt` as your first command would output, nor `file_demo,` (with the `,` on the end) as your 2nd command would output.

Comment: Actually \s means space, tab and line end.

Comment: You're assuming "space" means "blank". Of course when I said "space" I meant white-space as defined by the POSIX character class `[:space:]` which includes more than just the 3 chars you mentioned, i.e. carriage return, formfeed and vertical tab (I'm assuming by "line end" you meant linefeed)

Comment: The recent regexp change to `file_demo.*[\s]` will now match from `file_demo` to the last space character on the line. The `\s` doesn't have to be inside a bracket expression btw. I thought maybe `grep -oE 'file_demo\S*\w?'` would do it with GNU grep but that fails too (includes the `,` at the end) so idk... Hopefully the OP will clarify what a "word" is to them.

Answer (score 0):

GNU `AWK` solution. Let `file.txt` content be

```
For several generations, stories from Africa have traditionally been passed down by word of mouth. Often, after a hard day’s work, the adults would gather the children together by moonlight, around a village fire and tell stories. This was traditionally called 'Tales by Moonlight'. Usually, the stories are meant to prepare young people for life, and so each story taught a lesson or moral. file_demo_2021.txt In the African folktales, the stories reflect the culture where diverse types of animals abound. The animals and birds are often accorded human attributes, so it is not uncommon to find animals talking, singing, or demonstrating other human characteristics such as greed, jealousy, honesty, etc. The setting in many of the stories exposes the reader to the land form and climate within that region of Africa. References are often made to different seasons such as the 'dry' or 'rainy' season and their various effects on the surrounding vegetation and animal life.
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[[:space:]]"}/file_demo/' file.txt
```

output

```
file_demo_2021.txt
```

Explanation: I inform AWK to use any whitespace as row seperator (`RS`) thus I get one word per row. If said row match `file_demo` default action is taken - `print`ing.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: If the input was `foo file_demo, bar` that would output `file_demo,` (i.e. including the `,`) which I'm guessing would be undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `awk` using `patsplit()`:

```
awk 'patsplit($0,vals,/([[:alpha:]]+_){2}[[:digit:]]+[.][[:alpha:]]+/) { for (i in vals) print vals[i] }' file
file_demo_2021.txt
```

- You can see Ed Morton examples about `why does patsplit() exist?` going to  https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.awk/c/kBXXXeWMz-Y